# How does wpf know to set the Content property

Tags: c#, wpf

So if I create a button in XAML,

```
<Button />
```

I can set the content one of a few ways

```
<Button Content="My Content" />

<Button>
    My Content
</Button>

<Button>
   <Button.Content>
         My Content
   </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

and etc...

My question is, when a user passes content in this way

```
<Button>
    My Content
</Button>
```

how does wpf know to assign the Content dependency property? This is pretty neat functionality I'd like to build into my controls.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the Content property work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39841320/how-does-the-content-property-work)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from the [`[ContentProperty("Content")]` attribute](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpfsdk/2006/12/21/what-is-contentpropertyattribute/), which is set by [ContentControl](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/ContentControl.cs,27).

Comment: BOOM! Nice, great answer. Thank you for the speed.