# How does the Content property work

Tags: wpf, xaml

Both syntaxes below works.  My question is how does WPF know Content is what I specified?

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        my button
    </Button.Content>
</Button>

<Button>
     my button  <!--how does wpf know this is the content-->
</Button>
```

similarly, how does wpf know I'm now adding ListBoxItems

```
<ListBox>
    <!--ListBox.Items-->  
        <ListBoxItem Content="item 1" />  <!--XAML automatically knows I'm specifying items-->
        item 2
        <ListBoxItem Content="item 3" />
    <!--/ListBox.Items-->
</ListBox>
```

So in ContentControl, the default property is Content, and with ItemsControl, the default is Items, and with TextBox, the default is TextBox.
How does this 'default' work?
How do I create this 'default property' when I creat a Custom Control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ContentPropertyAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) tells xaml parser which property to use for direct content.

`ContentControl`, from which `Button` inherits, is marked with attibute `[ContentProperty("Content")]`. Similarly, `ItemsControl` (ancestor of `ListBox`) is marked with `[ContentProperty("Items")]`.